# Canvas.doDataUrl not working when image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I understood it will work only for local images.  Can anyone post working code that does this?

I've tried the following -

```
        var base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = ("/img.png");

        base_image.onload = function(){
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);

        }
```

and even entering my own URL

```
base_image.src = ("www.mywebsite.com/img.png");
```

Followed by -

```
    var str = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $("#myimg").attr("src", str);
```

Neither work.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `base_image.src` **after** `base_image.onload`:

```
    var base_image = new Image();
    base_image.onload = function(){
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
        var str = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $("#myimg").attr("src", str);
    }
    base_image.src = ("/img.png");
```

Comment: The canvas shows the image, it simply doesn't export it.  Made clearer after my edit

Comment: Put your toDataURL inside the onload.  Chronoligically, your toDataURL was being executed before your onload had actually loaded the image.  Any *put your src after the onload*.   ;)